# cloudbees folder plugin jobs in copied folders must be saved before they can be run

Tags: plugins, jenkins, directory, cloudbees

I'm having a look at the Cloudbees Jenkins Folder Plugin.  It looks like it will serve my purposes in allowing me to easily copy groups of jobs but...

When I copy a folder containing some jobs I have to click through Configure / Save for each job in the new folder before the Build option is available.  Is this expected behavior?

thanks

Glenn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, when a job is copied it is marked temporarily unbuildable until you save its configuration. This is essential in case the origin job was configured with a build trigger (like building on a schedule): you would not want the copied job to start running until you had a chance to check its configuration and perhaps make changes.

Comment: It would be a great help for me to be able to switch this feature off.  I'm using the Folders plugin to copy sets of jobs sometimes containing > 20 jobs.  Using Folders plugin allows me to have a one point config for the set of jobs but having to open and save every job adds a chunk of undesirable work.

Comment: It appears that I only have to edit and save one of the jobs in the folder to enable them all :)

Comment: I just copied another folder and did not have to edit and save any jobs in order to be able to run them.  There's behavior here that I don't yet understand.